# Is there a way to find out which markers you have used for labeling figures, tables, equations etc

Tags: equations, pdftex, numbering, labels

I've ran into an interesting problem. I normally mark my equations with p1:e1 ,..., pn:en, e.g. `\label{p1:e1}`. Is there a way for me to view all of the labels I have used previously without the need to skim through my document, so I can decide what to mark my future labels accordingly?

Comment: it's generally a bad idea to use numeric labels, especially if the number is any way related to the printed number in the document.

Comment: I mainly do this out of laziness due to large number of equations :D

Comment: but it is very confusing to anyone reading the source, when (say) equation 5 has label `e4`

Comment: Yep. Absolutely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you gave no example code I can not show you the result, but add `\usepackage{showkeys}` (see [on CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/showkeys)) to your preamble. Then all labels are showed in the pdf ...